# How do I replicate this (3D) metal texture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, 3ds-max, maya, cinema4d

I work with 3D models. I'm currently trying to replicate this solid kind of surface texturing as accurately as possible:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what I got by using chrome texturing. It's not close enough, there's too much shine and mirroring:

[image]

Can anyone recommend a more fitting texture as basis?

Comment: Where are you creating the texture? You tagged several different programs.

Comment: I'm free to choose between any of the 4, I would prefer to do it in Photoshop or Cinema 4D preferably since it's only a composing job with no need for animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK- I will weigh in here - you're in my wheelhouse.

### Point 1 - the material.

Your chrome shader's specularity is far too distinct - to get that satin metal texture (not brushed, which has distinct machining lines) you need to soften your specularity. You can do this with increased roughness, a specularity map which is grey versus black or white, or by finding appropriate pre-made materials in your **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tool of choice.

A better route you could take would be to opt for a more powerful material / shader solution using **PBR** methods (**P**hysically-**B**ased **R**endering) such as Allegorithmic Surfaces: given you mention both Maya and C4D, I think this last option might be a good move for you longer term.

Note that the hammer & sickle on map shot has visible dirt, scale and low-quality brushed-surface grain on the material - if it was a render versus a practical shot, then they used a PBR material which was very well set up with dirt layers - again, probably an Allegorithmic Surface or a Quixel Mixer scan to material.

**TL;DR**: you need realistic PBR materials to get photoreal renders.

### Point 2 - the lighting & environment

The other big difference in your setup is that all the other images you showed had good solid 3 or 4 point lighting setups on a solid light-coloured (high albedo) surface with GI, rim lights, pops and so on - your render is on a dark or no background, looks like no GI, and has one keylight and possibly a reflector (or that might be the HDRI environment) but is definitely not a carefully-set-up shot.

I'd start with the materials, but I'd also build yourself a template scene file which is set up as a photography / render studio, with lights and reflectors or at least a decent set of studio HDRI environments.

---

Couple examples of some of what I was talking about above:

Non-**PBR** but decent looking metal with spec and roughness maps, scratch maps etc - mine from several years back:
[image]

Recent image on Stephane Fontaine's Art Station showing Allegorithmic Substance Source material:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

At first: I do not have your 3D programs, only some simple to use freebies and low cost entry level stuff.

Check, if you can get acceptable result with simple non-photorealistic shading, select a grey color and define it be matt, not glossy:

[image]

Adjust rendering settings for good contrast.

You can add coarseness by placing a thin noisy image on the surface:

[image]

It's not a real 3D texture, only a nearly transparent image from Photoshop which has pixel noise.

These both could as well be plastic, you get better result with photorealistic rendering. Here the material is unpolished steel:

[image]

Different programs do same things differently. The next is again a non-photorealistic shading attempt, but this time there's more options. One can select an algorithm which generates metallic looking gradients:

[image]

**About chrome:** It's a mirror. Keep the chrome, have an environment which hasn't high nor sharp contrasts. That can fix your jet quickly.

The next maybe isn't useful in your case, because you have pro quality renderings capable 3D programs. Many of us use Illustrator, which can make only plastic looking 3D renderings. The next is in addition 2 separately revolved pieces. The result is quite far from metallic:

[image]

It can be fixed to some degree with an old metallization trick in Photoshop:

- insert a darker background
- apply curves to get weird solarization:

[image]

It could as well be glossy metal, if one didn't know how it was made.

Comment: Maybe there is a missunderstanding: I'm working with a 3D Model here.

Comment: @ChrisBean  The answer is fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is a brushed metal **shader** or **material** - not a texture. Textures have a specific meaning (usually a raster image of a real-world texture) in most CAD programs. Here's a little more explanation of that:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110707/shading-languages-vs-materials-in-3d-editors?rq=1

I've worked in many different CAD packages and in the past, I've used websites that provide a wide selection of free shaders. C4D and Blender are both pretty widely used packages - and while it's been a long time since I've used them, I was able to pretty quickly find websites that offered hundreds of free materials to download.

Here's a list of a few resources for C4D
https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/free-cinema-4d-textures-and-materials/